# php preg_replace ignores ^ in [ˆabc] construction

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, caret

The idea is to remove all non-alphabetic symbols from a string.

```
$string = "abcd  5858add";
print preg_replace('/[ˆa-z]/', '', $string)."\n"; //produces '  5858' (wrong)
print preg_replace('/[a-z]/', '', $string)."\n";  //produces '  5858' (right)
```

The first regexp should remove all non-alphabetic symbols.
The second should remove all alphabetic symbols.
But result is the same for both.
Why?

Tested on PHP 5.5.30, PHP 5.4.16

Comment: After posting my answer, I just noticed your title which shows the problem quite clearly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the caret, that's the circumflex accent.

Use `[^a-z]` instead of `[ˆa-z]`.

Comment: Great! Thank you.
P.S. That is MAC layout trick: Shift+6 give circumflex and Shift+6 and Space give a caret.